# Как задать необходимый порядок в списке <ol> в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Есть список, который необходимо расположить в порядке убывания соответствующих значений в `input`. Строка с максимальным значением `input` должна быть в самом верху, а минимальным в самом низу списка(должен быть порядок по убыванию). Все это должно произойти при нажатии на кнопку. К кнопке пока не привязал, суть в работе функции.

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll("li");
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
function rev() {
  var max = 0;
  var stab = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    if(max < parseInt(inputs[i].value)) {
      list[stab].before(list[i]);
      max = parseInt(inputs[i].value);
      stab = i;
    }  
  }
  console.log(max);
  console.log(stab);
}
rev();
```

```html
<h1>Just Test</h1>
<ol>
 <li id="t1">One <input type="number" value="1"></li>
 <li id="t2">Two <input type="number" value="2"></li>
 <li id="t3">Three <input type="number" value="3"></li>
 <li id="t4">For <input type="number" value="4"></li>
</ol>
<button>Sort</button>
```

В таком исполнении все работает как надо, но если поменять значение `input` в 3 строке, например на 5, то код уже работает неверно.

Comment: Вы можете [поправить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/713825/edit) вопрос вместо комментария.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
sort.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  let a = [], b;
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("ol > li"), (c)=>a.push([c.children[0].value,c]));
  b = a.sort((a,b)=>b[0]-a[0]);
  b.forEach((c)=>c[1].parentNode.appendChild(c[1]));
});
```

```html
<h1>Just Test</h1>
<ol>
 <li id="t1">One <input type="number" value="1"></li>
 <li id="t2">Two <input type="number" value="2"></li>
 <li id="t3">Three <input type="number" value="3"></li>
 <li id="t4">For <input type="number" value="4"></li>
</ol>
<button id="sort">Sort</button>
```

Comment: Необходимо, чтобы этот пронумерованный список со своими значениями отобразился в соответствующем порядке, а не сами числа.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov обновлён

Comment: Работает! Благодарю. Просьба, если не затруднит, то поясните комментариями код, который вы написали. Буду признателен.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let ol = document.querySelector('ol');
let lis = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')];

function sort() {
  // удаляем все элементы <li> из <ol>
  for (let li of lis) {
    li.remove();
  }

  lis
    // преобразуем массив элементов <li> в массив пар [элемент <li>, соответствующий ему <input>]
    .map(li => [li, li.querySelector('input')])
    // сортируем массив пар
    .sort((a, b) => b[1].value - a[1].value)
    // добавляем все элементы <li> в <ol>
    .forEach(pair => ol.appendChild(pair[0]));
}

sort();

// вешаем обработчик на кнопку
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', sort);
```

```html
<h1>Just Test</h1>
<ol>
  <li id="t1">One <input type="number" value="1"></li>
  <li id="t2">Two <input type="number" value="2"></li>
  <li id="t3">Three <input type="number" value="3"></li>
  <li id="t4">For <input type="number" value="4"></li>
</ol>
<button>Sort</button>
```

Comment: Работает! Благодарю. Мне еще учиться и учиться.))